# Route for sound file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to play some alert in my project. Is there any gem for it? Right now I am doing this using html5 and jquery. My code is

```
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto">
  <source src="http://www.wav-sounds.com/cartoon/bugsbunny1.wav"></source>
</audio>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
        console.log(audio);
        $(".post-comment-button").click(function() {
            audio.play();
        });
</script>
```

This is working just fine. But If use any sound file from my assets/audios folder the sound don't play because no route found for the file. I tried this

```
<source src="/assets/test.mp3">
```

How can I solve this? Do I have to create a controller for this and then add in the route file or I can do this without creating a contoller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just place it directly in the public folder. Or create a 'sounds' subfolder there. Everything in public can be directly accessed. Assets are more for things that need some preprocessing and he results of this then are made available.